# Need some help getting rid of white space between two div tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hoping someone can help me get rid of this whitespace in my code. I have tried setting `*{margin:0}` and the same for `p` and `pre` tags, but that isnt really helping. I am using BS4. The code is

```
    <div class="jumbotron container context" style="padding-bottom:3; padding-top:40">
<h1 class="bg-info">aaa</h1>
<pre>fsfsdfsd
fasfdds
fdsfsfsd
fdsfasdfsd
fdsfsdf
</pre>
</div><div class="jumbotron container" style="padding:0;">
<div class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" id="carousel_controls">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <a href="https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" target="_blank">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded mx-auto d-block" src="https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev" href="#carousel_controls" role="button">
        <span aria:hidden="true" class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next" href="#carousel_controls" role="button">
        <span aria:hidden="true" class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As can be seen in the screenshot, i am trying to get rid of the white space in the red box.

[image: gap]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qesrjxne/)

Comment: No one will be able to help you without a live demo. Either post a link or recreate the issue on jsfiddle.

Comment: Don't just post a link (to either the site or jsfiddle). Provide the code in the question itself. See [mcve]. You should be careful with unitless values though (`padding-bottom:3`). Zero is the only value that should be unitless.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle that is minimal @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you become familiar with the Developer Tools (DevTools) in your favorite browser. Almost all browsers include DOM/Element Inspectors which make diagnosing problems like this easy.

Comment: @Makyen I would really appreciate if you can elaborate on that a bit. My core issue was that I wasnt aware that jumbotron had a margin styling attribute. Most of my googling revealed that information about p and pre. As I am building the template for this page, i am using devtools to debug most of my scripts and layouts are working, but how would i know (using devtools) that margin-bottom was available for jumbotron?

Comment: @securisec Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Makyen Predominantly Chrome, but also Safari to test with

Comment: @securisec For Chrome, it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQNvQ.gif). As you can see, the rules applied for the element you select are displayed in the view to the right. It even shows you where the rule originated (e.g. which file it's contained in). The Computed tab shows a graphical representation of the box model. Other browsers are quite similar, but I haven't tried it on Safari.

Comment: @Makyen Thank you so much for this. This is fantastic knowledge! I am not a web dev, so I was never really sure that that ability existed. This will surely cut down my googling by 95% and bad SO posts by 100%. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it happens because of the margin bottom applied on `.jumbotron`. You just have to override that style

```
.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

However, it will be a great idea if you add another class to the jumbotrons that are not going to have margin bottom. For example

```
.jumbotron.your-custom-class { margin-bottom: 0px}
```

Comment: @securisec & David Note that there's no need to resort to `!important` here. A) the element is already using a `style` applied via HTML. Thus, it might be easy to just add the `margin-bottom:0;` to the already existing `style` (but this has similar problems to using `!important`). B) Adding an additional class, or some other selector (depends on what's wanted), is good, if there are some `.jumboton` elements which you don't want to have with `margin-bottom:0;`. However, `!important` is unneeded, as an additional class gives more specificity.

Comment: C) If you want to override the CSS for all of `.jumboton`, then it's usually better to just use a CSS rule with more specificity (e.g. `.jumbotron.jumbotron {margin-bottom: 0;}`). Generally, avoiding using `!important`, when possible, is usually desirable, as using it has a tendency to have unintended consequences (i.e. disrupt other CSS; e.g. a `:hover` effect).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about CSS @Makyen. I will get rid of the `!important`

Comment: You're right! The `!important` is not needed. Edited

Comment: Depending on where in the page you place the CSS, you may, or may not need the additional specificity. CSS works that the rules most recently processed will override other rules with the same specificity. Thus `.jumbotron {margin-bottom: 0px;}` will work, but must be placed in the page after the CSS which defines the `margin-bottom: 2rem;` for `.jumbotron`.

Comment: Exactly. In simple terms, @securisec, this means that you have to first load the Bootstrap CSS and then your own stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 has **native classes** for handling all of your spacing needs. And it is recommended that you use Bootstrap classes (instead of css hacks) because css hacks have the tendency to require even more css hacks down the road to fix the problems caused by the original css hacks.

To fix the problem using Bootstrap 4 classes alone, just add the `mb-0` class to the `jumbotron` class. That's it!

`mb-0` means "margin-bottom:0" and will produce the desired effect without the need for any unnecessary css hacks.

I've also replaced some of your other css with native Bootstrap 4 classes and look how much cleaner it makes your code look (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="jumbotron container context mb-0 pb-5 pt-5">
    <h1 class="bg-info">aaa</h1>
    <pre>fsfsdfsd
    fasfdds
    fdsfsfsd
    fdsfasdfsd
    fdsfsdf
    </pre>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron container p-0">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" id="carousel_controls">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <a href="https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" target="_blank">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded mx-auto d-block" src="https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev" href="#carousel_controls" role="button">
                <span aria:hidden="true" class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next" href="#carousel_controls" role="button">
                <span aria:hidden="true" class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`pb-5` means "padding-bottom 5 units"; `pt-5` is "padding-top 5 units" and `p-0` is "padding:0" all around.

More regarding spacing classes:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Note that your carousel isn't currently working and I left the code for that unchanged because that wasn't your question but if you want to fix it, have a look at this page:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: Thanks! This is really good information! And the carousel is working...

Comment: WebDevBooster (& FYI @securisec), Using these CSS classes is significantly more of a hack than using what you refer to as other "CSS hacks". These classes use `!important`, which has a strong tendency to disrupt other formatting (e.g. preventing assigning a `:hover`, or *any other* CSS without also using `!important`). While using these might be superior to using a `style` HTML attribute, it's equivalent to doing so, and is certainly *not* superior to using CSS to appropriately assign the values you desire based on a more complex selector (e.g. based on the structure of the page). (continued)

Comment: Frankly, using these is as antithetical to the concept of CSS as it is to be assigning a `style` to each element (which is, conceptually, *exactly* how these are being used, and how they are *intended* to be used).

Comment: @Makyen You are correct in regards to the "concept of CSS" and I totally agree with that as far as the "concept of CSS" goes. **However...** what we are dealing here with is the Bootstrap **framework** and while adding a class for every little thing is definitely "antithetical to the concept of CSS" and a disadvantage of this framework in general, this framework does have a number of very strong advantages as well. And in modern front-end web development, those advantages most certainly outweigh the disadvantages. By a long shot! You could say it's a trade-off and it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get another problem in line: `<div class="jumbotron container context" style="padding-bottom:3; padding-top:40">`

```
padding-bottom:3; padding-top:40
```

when set value in css (padding, margin, width, height... ) it should has dimensions like (px, %, em...), more info [the length of css - css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/) or [css-unit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

> maybe fix: "padding-bottom:3px; padding-top:40px"